# Deprecation Warning - Compass Unsemantic

Tags: ruby, sass

Estou tendo um problema quanto a compilação de alguns códigos SASS + Compass + Unsemantic que gera o seguinte aviso:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING on line 17 of /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-unsemantic-0.1.5/stylesheets/compass-unsemantic/_unsemantic-grid-desktop.sass:
  @extending an outer selector from within @media is deprecated.
  You may only @extend selectors within the same directive.
  This will be an error in Sass 3.3.
  It can only work once @extend is supported natively in the browser.
```

Esse aviso sempre aparece quando eu compilo o código, e gera na verdade dezenas deles, enchendo todo o terminal do mesmo. Infelizmente não encontrei nada a respeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que existe um problema de compatibilidade entre Unsemantic e SASS 3.3.
No link abaixo, o autor do Unsemantic afirma que o warning pode ser ignorado sem qualquer problema.

Quando o SASS suportar o operador `@at-root`, o Unsemantic vai ser actualizado e o warning vai ser corrigido.

Parece que, por agora, usar o SASS 3.2 pode resolver o warning.

Fonte: [Unsemantic Issue: deprecation warning upon compile #3](https://github.com/nathansmith/unsemantic/issues/3)